# Codeigniter 3 en servidor gratuito

Tags: servidor, codeigniter-3

Subir mis archivos codeigniter al servidor runhosting.com, configure todo.
Este es mi archivo
.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?tramites2021.atwebpages.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|css|js|images|robots.txt|assets|files|documentos)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$config['base_url'] .= preg_replace('@/+$@','',dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])).'/';
```

El error que me sale es:
Error 403 - Forbidden: You don't have permission to access this page or directory listing on the server.

This error code indicates that the page or directory listing you are trying to view is forbidden and not accessible currently.

Answer (score 0):

A mí me salía el mismo error y agregué este código. Espero te sirva.

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName tudominio.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/carpeta/index.php
    <Directory /var/www/html/carpeta/index.php>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName tudominio.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/carpeta/index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer].

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).